# Aspects are not executed

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-aop

I'm trying to test a simple Aspect.
The app compiles and runs fine, BUT I do not get the Aspect executed. Or at least, I do not get the output the aspect should produce.
(my aim is to write an exception logger for any ex that occures in the app. but first this test aspect should run...)

Maybe someone who has more experience in aspects see's what I'm doing wrong?

```
package business;
public interface Customer {
    void addCustomer();
}

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class CustomerImpl implements Customer {

    public void addCustomer() {
        System.out.println("addCustomer() is running ");
    }
}



@RequestScoped @Named
//this is backing bean for jsf page
public class Service {

     @Inject
     Customer cust;

    add() {
        System.out.println("Service is running ");
        cust.addCustomer();
    }
}


@Aspect
public class AspectComp {
    @Before("within(business..*)")
    public void out() {
     System.out.println("system out works!!");
 }
}
```

Spring:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    ">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="business" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
</beans>
```

Output:

```
Service is running 
addCustomer() is running
```

The Aspect statement is missing.

Comment: What does your Spring configuration look like?

Comment: Updated above stripped down to the hopefully important info. The only config I changed in spring config for aspects are the *.xsd and <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />.

Comment: You are creating your Component with its constructor, and not getting it from Spring container! That's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating your Component with its constructor, and not getting it from Spring container! That's the problem, or you must use AspectJ's load-time weaver.

Just inject your component (CustomerImpl) in your service and then use the injected instance.

Comment: +1 Almost. But don't inject by type (CustomerImpl), inject by interface (Customer)

Comment: modified above with: `@Inject Customer cust;` but the behaviour is still the same: no aspect executed.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar problem once; Spring wasn't actually loading the proxy as it did not recognize the @Aspect annotation as being an annotation-scanable bean.  I added the @Component annotation to the @Aspect notation and Spring started scanning it.

I never looked into the reasons why this happened, and why I needed to do that, so I cannot confirm that is the "proper" way of doing things.  My gut would tell me that I had something missing in my config file; I can't imagine why Spring would not scan for @Aspect beans.

The other thing you can do, is to explicitly declare your Aspect bean in the XML config file as well to see if this the same type of problem you're having.

You can also enable debug logging in the Spring framework and see if your bean is being loaded by Spring.  If not, then it gives you an idea where to start looking.